# Java Applet consuming client-side dotnet framework redistributable

Tags: c#, java, .net, interop, applet

I need to access and use some image manipulation api's other than java's, so is it possible to access the windows .net redistributable api's from a java applet that is signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: It depends.

There's a pretty good series of [articles](http://www.devx.com/interop/Door/18896) on Java/.NET interop.

Long Answer: To access features of the .NET runtime library you'll need to wrap them in your own code to expose them as com objects which you can then use with jni.